# APIからjsonを得た後にページをロードするとjsonが読めなくなる

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

reactを用いて、ダミーのユーザ情報をjsonで返すAPIからデータをロードするコードを書いております。以下のようなものです。

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&nat=us&inc=gender,name,email`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setUsers(json));
  }, []);

  return (
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
      {users.results.map((result) => {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{result.name.first}</td>
            <td>{result.gender}</td>
            <td>{result.email}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );
}

export default App;
```

このコードを実行すると`TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null`というエラーが表示されてしまいます。しかし一方で`return(<table>...</table>)`内が

```
  return users ? (
    <h1>
      {users.results.map((result) => {
        return result.name.first;
      })}
    </h1>
  ) : (
    <p>Loading...</p>
  );
```

のコードの後、最初のコードを実行するとテーブルが表示されます。再度ロードすると、`TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null`が表示されます。
2番目のコードは再ロード後も正常に実行されます。`users.results.map()`は同じにもかかわらず、なぜこのような違いが生じるのでしょうか。またどうすればエラーが生じなくなるでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `useState()`の引数に指定するのはstateの初期値です。また[`useEffect()`が動くのはレンダー後](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks)なので、まず最初に初期値でレンダリングが行われます。Reactクラスを使った場合も副作用は`componentDidMount`(DOMのレンダー後)に処理を書いていたと思いますが。

Comment: ご指摘の通りです。useEffect()のレンダーのタイミングについての理解があいまいでした。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> なぜこのような違いが生じるのでしょうか。

後半のコードでは `users` が `null` でないかどうか(正確には `truthy` であるかどうか)をチェックしていますが、前半のコードではチェックしていません。

これに加えて、[初期値](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable)を `null` としている

```js
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
```

ため、常にエラーが発生します。

> どうすればエラーが生じなくなるでしょうか。

1つめの方法は、後半のコードと同様、 `users` の `null` チェックを行うことです。

```js
      {users ? (
        users.results.map((result) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{result.name.first}</td>
              <td>{result.gender}</td>
              <td>{result.email}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <tr>
          <td>Loading...</td>
          <td>Loading...</td>
          <td>Loading...</td>
        </tr>
      )}
```

2つめの方法は、初期値を適切に設定し`null`となるような状況を無くすことです。

```js
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({ results: [] });
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。なぜエラーが発生していたのか理解できました。